# What is the general recipe for making https requests with the wreq library?

Tags: haskell, https

I am trying to use [Network.Wreq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.3.0.1/docs/Network-Wreq.html) to make https requests. I am following the [wreq tutorial](http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/tutorial.html) as well as consulting the documentation for the package. I am using [WordsApi](https://www.wordsapi.com/) for my test queries.

If I use `curl` to send the GET query:

```
curl "https://www.wordsapi.com/words/test?accessToken=myTokenHere"
```

I get the JSON data returned as expected. So I know my token is correct. However, if I try to run wreq's `get` function in `ghci` (I'm actually using `cabal repl`, but that shouldn't matter, right?)

```
get "https://www.wordsapi.com/words/test?accessToken=myTokenHere"
```

then I get the following exception:

```
*** Exception: TlsException (HandshakeFailed (Error_Protocol ("expecting server hello, got alert :
[(AlertLevel_Fatal,HandshakeFailure)]",True,HandshakeFailure)))
```

I have seen solutions to similar problems given for the Http.Conduit library, but I don't know how to translate them to apply to wreq.

I would ultimately like to use wreq for POST requests, but I am hoping that if I can figure out how to make valid https GET requests, that solution should transfer to POST requests too.

Any help, or requests for further information, is very much appreciated.

---

Specs:

- wreq 0.3.0.1
- GHC 7.8.3

Comment: There is an open issue with tls and certain MS servers: https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-tls/issues/87 which might be the problem.

Comment: For the time being, I have simply moved all my https stuff into a little python script. (Very handy for me, since the tweepy python-twitter api is a breeze - I was able to learn the needed python, install library, and get it working in less time than it took me to puzzle out the opening paragraphs of the documentation for the `twitter-conduit` Haskell lib). I recommend people "just trying to get the job done" explore similar solutions as temporary fixes. I will try to get the thing to be all in Haskell at some point.

Comment: it just occurred to me that there are Haskell bindings to libcurl, and even though it hasn't been updated in a while it might another way to go. [(link)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/curl)

Comment: I just tried using `wget` and got his error: `ERROR: certificate common name `ssl2000.cloudflare.com' doesn't match requested host name `www.wordsapi.com'.` So maybe that's really the problem.

Comment: I created a new issue for this: https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-tls/issues/101